# .NET CF Listbox that can scroll like iPhone

Tags: .net, compact-framework

Any know any Listbox control that can scroll with momentum like the iPhone's listbox? (Free / OpenSource preferable)

EDIT: NO? REALLY Nothing for .NET CF that can scroll like iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like [this one on Codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/SmoothListBox.aspx)?